# Using a variable to create a variable

Tags: sql, ssis, dts

I have an execute SQL task that finds the path of the latest backup of a database and populates a variable with it (**User::BackupFilePath**)

I want to pass that into another task that will generate a restore database script and populate another variable to be used to restore the database.

```
Select (
'ALTER DATABASE [Database] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

RESTORE DATABASE [Database] 
FROM  DISK = ''' + **BackupFilePath** + '''  WITH  FILE = 1, NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 5 

ALTER DATABASE [Database] SET MULTI_USER
GO'
) as RestoreScript
```

The second part that would generate the string is however returning this error message

```
[Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "Select 'ALTER DATABASE [xxxx..." failed with the following error: "An error occurred while extracting the result into a variable of type (DBTYPE_I4)". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition

Comment: Should there be not semicolons between the commands?

Answer (score 1):

So far, it looks like you're having a simple problem:  the variable you're setting, to your command string, needs to be a string datatype.

Your error message mentions `DBTYPE_I4`, which is a long integer: 
 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms711251%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Whereas what you'd save a command string into, would be a string type such as `DBTYPE_STR` or `DBTYPE_WSTR` (see the link above), which in SSIS would commonly be called `DT_STR` (for ASCII strings) or `DT_WSTR` (for Unicode strings) -- see the link below: 
 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141036.aspx

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause is the property 'ResulSet' of your second SQL Task (the restore)/
Make sure it's set to 'None'